# Is there a program like MobaXTerm for Linux systems? (SFTP GUI browser & terminal)

Tags: ssh, sftp, terminal-emulator, file-manager

I am coming from Windows, where I ran the program [MobaXTerm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).
Essentially I used it as an SSH client (though it has other uses). It has a great feature of showing the files and directories on the left hand side, while showing the terminal on the right side of the screen. This let me execute Linux commands from the terminal as well as easily drag and drop files.

My question is:
**Is there a program likes this for Linux? One that displays the files/directories on one half and the terminal on the other?**

Filezilla doesn't have a terminal I can execute commands on, but I like the drag and drop file usage.
PuTTY has a great terminal for command-line execution, but does not have a drag and drop feature that lets me easily view, create, delete, and access files/directories.

Thanks!

Here is a view of MobaXTerm's SFTP graphical/terminal style that I am looking for:
[image: MobaXTerm view]

*Note: if this is the wrong place to ask, or I am asking the question wrong, please let me know and I will go to the right source or rephrase my question.*

Comment: I would recommend you http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ though I don't think there is something like that. Unix idea is having single tool to do single job well, not all the jobs at once.

Comment: Use `sshfs` and whatever GUI filemanager+terminal you want

Answer (score 14):

I found an alternative in asbru

https://www.asbru-cm.net/

It has a lateral tab where you can save your connections

Cheers

Comment: looks promising

Comment: Beyond promising. I just installed it and it is Fraking AWESOME! So many configurable items!

Comment: can't install it on Ubuntu 20. followed the two installation lines on the main site but receieved: "Unable to locate package asbru-cm"

Comment: @aderchox Hmm, give it another try. Just worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Comment: 2022 October : I tried this https://www.asbru-cm.net/ in a fresh ubuntu 20 and I got the error : **Unable to locate package asbru-cm** :(

Comment: I tried the manual installation and worked https://github.com/asbru-cm/asbru-cm/wiki/Manual-installation#start-application

Comment: Yeah, they don't list it as a package on Ubuntu; you have to install it from their repo.

Answer (score 9):

I came across this problem myself and the best way I found around it was to use MobaXterm's `portable exe` and run it using `wine` on `Ubuntu`.

It worked perfectly for my use case on `Ubuntu 20.04`. Both the terminal and side panel's file browsing work exactly as you'd expect on Windows.

At the time of writing this, the MobaXterm portable version could be downloaded from [here](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download-home-edition.html).
Once you have installed `wine` on your linux distro, you simply need to unzip the file downloaded from the above link (thus revealing the `portable exe`) and run the `exe` as:

```
wine /path/to/MobaXterm/Portable/exe
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd recommend [terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html) mobaxterm was my terminator replacement when I shifted back to Windows. You won't find a drag and drop window like you have in windows unfortunately but the hot keys in terminator - oh how I miss the hot keys.

Linux Mint has simple file tools available in Files:
Files -> File -> Connect to server ...
[image]

There are separate SCP tools available for Mint:
https://krusader.org/
https://www.gftp.org/
etc.

Comment: I will take a look at it. I am running Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon

Comment: Terminator is not really comparable to MobaXTerm. It's virtually just the hotkeys mentioned and split terminal. It does add some cool stuff to the regular terminal. It is not a fully featured alternative to MobaXTerm though.

Answer (score 6):

You can try `snowflake`: install with

```
sudo snap install snowflake
```

I was also looking for an alternative app for Mobxterm and I found this one. It has much more features like:

- SSH + SFTP
- built-in text editor
- process monitor
- system monitor
- ssh key management

  ...

[image: sftp]

[image: text editor]
[image]

Comment: Seems decent, but it's written in Java...So I'll pass and probably just stick with MobaXTerm with Wine or give Asbru a try.

Comment: @ZaxLofful Oh you poor thing, what did Java do to you? I think of my own Java days with horror but that's because of my own poor coding practices. There are lots of large and well maintained programs written in Java like Apache Cassandra and Kafka.

Comment: @PavinJoseph: It has severe exploits almost yearly....It did that to the world. Not to mention it's slow. I digress, for those interested; I tried MobaXTerm with WINE and its garbage.

Comment: @ZaxLofful FWIW, I ended up using Filezilla and Konsole, at least konsole has terminal muxing built-in. If you're intent on using Moba, perhaps try running it with Bottles and different runners (soda, wine, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu at both ends,

1. Open files folder in your local ubuntu machine. Click on "+ other locations" in left of your window.
2. You can see **connect to server** option at the end.
3. Enter IP (eg: "**sftp://10.xx.xx.xx/**"). click on connect, it asks for username and password.
4. After entering username and password correctly, you can access any file from server. It feels like you are using server machine directly.

Comment: This works with a non-Ubuntu system on the other side as well :) just checked with CentOS and I even remember connecting to Windows this way.

Comment: This worked for me like a charm! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best alternative for MobaXTerm for Linux systems is **remmina**

https://remmina.org/

They are support sftp graphical/terminal, ssh client, rdp, vnc and much more..

full features list can be found here: https://remmina.org/remmina-features/

some pics from remmina's website

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! Could you provide more detail on what features does this tool has to do what the original poster wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) client. It has option of drag and drop and is easy to

Comment: "easy to"? Easy to use?

Comment: My bad, it was a typo error. What I meant was that  it's easy to use.